# using pipe to run command in background

Tags: shell, io-redirection

I was reading [this question on rpi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/player-with-harware-aceleration-for-tcp-stream) and noticed an interesting line that got me thinking:

```
mkfifo tcp.stream
nc -l -p 1234 > tcp.stream | omxplayer --live tcp.stream
```

Notice the io redirection. STDOUT is redirected twice! My concern is that omxplayer not having STDIN associated with anything usable might be a little hard to control, but I think this does have the advantage of killing nc with SIGPIPE when omxplayer exits. Is this a good idea? Is this something worth recommending in some odd cases?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The pipe will immediately get closed on `nc`'s end.  When `omxplayer` dies `nc` will receive SIGPIPE on writing to the fifo, not to the pipe.

It might be better to just run `nc` in the background so that you could keep control over `omxplayer` via stdin.

```
mkfifo tcp.stream
nc -l -p 1234 > tcp.stream &
omxplayer --live tcp.stream
```

However, using `|` instead of `&` actually makes sense in the view of shell's job control.

Using `|`:

```
$ mkfifo fifo
$ nc -l -p 1234 >fifo | cat fifo
```

`nc` and `cat` belong to the same process group (PGID 9177).

```
$ ps f -o pid,ppid,pgid,command
  PID  PPID  PGID COMMAND
 9095  1681  9095 bash
 9179  9095  9179  \_ ps f -o pid,ppid,pgid,command
 1691  1681  1691 bash
 9177  1691  9177  \_ nc -l -p 1234
 9178  1691  9177  \_ cat fifo
```

Both of them receive SIGINT then quit when user types <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Using `&`:

```
$ mkfifo fifo
$ nc -l -p 1234 >fifo & cat fifo
[1] 9183
```

`nc` and `cat` belong to different process groups (PGID 9183 and 9184).

```
$ ps f -o pid,ppid,pgid,command
  PID  PPID  PGID COMMAND
 9095  1681  9095 bash
 9185  9095  9185  \_ ps f -o pid,ppid,pgid,command
 1691  1681  1691 bash
 9183  1691  9183  \_ nc -l -p 1234
 9184  1691  9184  \_ cat fifo
```

In this case, only foreground process (`cat`) receives SIGINT when user types <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.  If `nc` doesn't yet get connected, it remains running in the background.

```
^C
$ jobs
[1]+  Running                 nc -l -p 1234 > fifo &
$ kill %
[1]+  Terminated              nc -l -p 1234 > fifo
```

Comment: I was hoping someone would mention this. And it isn't just *`CTRL+C`* - the backgrounded processes would keep running even on a shell exit unless job-controlled were specifically enabled w/ `set -m` for a scripted shell. Run in the pipeline like that they should all be quit at the same time - or suspended together, even - if the parent shell quits or is suspended.

Comment: `sh -c 'nc -l -p 1234 > tcp.stream & omxplayer --live tcp.stream'` would have the same effect of running `nc` and `omxplayer` in the same process group.

Comment: I think this latter thing^ needs `-m`.